# How do I select rows with at least a value in some selected columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe of the form:

```py
ID Address1 Address2 Address3
0  a        b        c
1  NaN      d        e
2  f        NaN      g
2  NaN      h        Nan
```

How could I select all rows that have (at least in one of them), a value in either Address1 column, or Address3?

In this particular example, it will select row 0,1 and 2, not 3 because both Address1 and Address3 are Nan.

Thanks!

Comment: Try df[df[['Address1', 'Address3']].any(1)]

Comment: Try this : `df[(df['Address1'].notnull()) | (df['Address3'].notnull())]`